# VideoPlayer error loading video only plays sound - Warning: Removing channel layout 0x3, redundant with 2 channels

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, video-player

I am trying to use VideoPlayer to load a local video. The program runs fine when it is standalone (in its own file). But, when I bring it into my main program, it loads the video but only plays the sound. I get an error (warning, to be more precise) message:

> [WARNING] [ffpyplayer  ] [ffpyplayer_abuffersink @ 000001e84fb55580]
> Removing channel layout 0x3, redundant with 2 channels

Here's the standalone version:

```
import cv2
from kivy.uix.videoplayer import VideoPlayer
from kivymd.app import MDApp


class PlayVid(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        player = VideoPlayer(source="Roadhouse.mp4")
        player.state = "play"
        player.options = {"eos": "stop"}
        player.allow_stretch = True

        return player


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PlayVid().run()
```

And here is the same thing split in functions and class in my main program:

```
class PlayVid(MDApp):

    def playnow(self):
        # player = VideoPlayer(source='Roadhouse.mp4')
        # player.state = "play"
        video = VideoPlayer(source='Roadhouse.mp4')
        video.state = "play"
        # player.options = {"eos": "stop"}
        # player.allow_stretch = True
        return video


class SecondWindow(Screen):
    def build (self):
        sm = ScreenManager()

        self.sec_screen = SecondWindow()

        sm.add_widget(self.sec_screen)

        return sm

    def start_play(self):

        PlayVid.playnow(self)
```

A kv button in SecondWindow triggers start_play and then PlayVid.playnow(self). That's all. It runs, loads the file, and then just plays the sound. No video.

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. Help?

Thanks!

I created a standalone program for it, and it works. I just can't understand why it drops the video and plays the sound when brought into the main program.

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but your `PlayVid.playnow(self)` results in the `playnow()` method getting the wrong `self`. Try replacing that line with `MDApp.get_running_app().playnow()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `playnow()` method returns the `VideoPlayer` widget, but that return is ignored. You must add that widget to your GUI in order to see it. Try using this version of `start_play()`:

```
def start_play(self):

    v = MDApp.get_running_app().playnow()
    self.add_widget(v)
```

Comment: YUP! You knocked it out of the park. My brain was fried trying to figure this out. Thank you!!!! You rock @John-Anderson!